# Tabbar not showing when i select flyout item in xamarine forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im new to xamarine forms, Please guide me what i did wrong, I wanted the tabbars stay visible either i select any flyout item...

```
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

    <FlyoutItem Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True" Title="Info" Icon="home.png">
        <ShellSection>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}"/>
        </ShellSection>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True" Title="Settings" Icon="card.png">
        <ShellSection>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}"/>
        </ShellSection>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted the tabbars stay visible either i select any flyout item...

If you want the same Tabbar then you would need to specify that tab bar for each flyout item.  But, the four home ShellContents, you could put in the Home tab.

[image]

**Xaml:**

```
 <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="tab_chat.png">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Home1"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
            Icon="tab_chat.png" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Home2"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
            Icon="tab_chat.png" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Home3"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
            Icon="tab_chat.png" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Home4"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
            Icon="tab_chat.png" />
    </Tab>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Info"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
        Icon="tab_about.png" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Settings"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
        Icon="tab_feed.png" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: thanx @Wendy for your reply, but i don't want this . I want the bottom tabbar to stay visible, when i click on any flyout item and i don't want the tabs to specify for each flyout item...

Comment: The bottom tabbar which stay visable need to specify that tabbar for each flyout item. We could not make the tabbar stay at bottom without specifying for the flayout item.